# Please use a different workspace. This workspace is already in use in another JupyterLab window. Please enter another workspace name

Tags: jupyter-lab

When i set up a jupyterlab in my vps,it shows this forever again when i type something.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JFrs.jpg)